# Dynamically generated id in tomahwak dataList (JSF 1.2)

Tags: jsf-1.2, tomahawk

I cannot figure out how to generate dynamically id for elements in `<t:dataList>` which is inside `<t:dataTable>`. Code looks more or less like this :

```
<t:dataTable value="#{SomeBean.foo}" var="item">
    <h:column rendered="true">
      <div id="divpvmu">
        <t:dataList value="#{item.templates}" var="template" rowCountVar="templateIndex">
            <div id="saveBtn">
            </div>
        </t:dataList>
      </div>
    </h:column>
```

Obiously this code generate some number of divs with the same id="saveBtn"
. I would like to have distinct id for every generated div. I was trying to do this by this change :

> `<div id="saveBtn_#{templateIndex}">`

, however then I'm getting an exception

> `javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: java.io.IOException: Example.jsp(50,31) JBWEB004178: #{..} is not allowed in template text`

Is there any way to generate distinct id's for such a construction ? I'm using JSF 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

There is the `<t:div>` tag. It allows you to use EL expression in id attribute.

So something like this should do the job:

```
<t:div id="saveBtn_#{templateIndex}" forceId="true">
```

JSF should also automatically generate id for you:

```
    <t:dataList id="myList" value="#{item.templates}" var="template">
        <t:div id="saveBtn">
        </t:div>
    </t:dataList>
```

This tag in t:dataTable, t:dataList and so on will generate id like:

`myList:0:saveBtn` for first element,
`myList:1:saveBtn` for second element, and so on.